# Proof of implicit functions theorem in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-writing, manifolds, implicit-function-theorem, submanifold

I have not been able to track down a proof of the following **theorem**:

Let $h:(M,\mathcal{U},\mathcal{F}) \to (M',\mathcal{U}',\mathcal{F}')$ be a smooth mapping between differential manifolds (U - open cover, F - atlas of charts) of dimensions m and m'. Suppose that for some $q\in M'$, $dh_p:T_p M \to T_{h(p)} M'$ is surjective for any $p\in N = h^{-1}q$. Then $N\subseteq M$ is  a submanifold of dimension m-m' and the tangent space at $p\in N$ is given by $T_p N = \text{ker}~dh_p$.

Can you help?

Comment: Look, for example, at the proof of the Local Submersion Theorem on p. 20 of Guillemin and Pollack.

Comment: I also managed to find this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275459/proof-of-preimage-theorem-for-abstract-manifolds with an answer that goes well with what you referenced. So, yes, I take it as a proof. as per Guillemin & Pollack.

Comment: Another reference: see theorems 4.7 and 4.8 in these notes: http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgak/manifolds/notes2017.pdf